# How to pass component into router-outlet

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an app component an its use router-outlet, and a main component (what is loaded at router-outlet)
Now I would like to place packages in that component where we can insert widgets.

App component:

```
<cover></cover>

<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="stretch">
    <div fxFlex>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main component:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<main-widget></main-widget> //place where I would like to load custom content

<left-widget></left-widget>  //place where I would like to load custom content

<right-widget></right-widget>  //place where I would like to load custom content
```

**Main component is come from a coreModul**(share module) - this is a framework **we have no access to it on project level.**

So I would like to put content into widgets, but have no idea how to do that.

The hard thing to me is how to pass a component into a router-outlet and show it in right place. Its possible to use ng-templates in this case?

**EDIT:**

App routing:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { 
    LoginComponent, 
    LoginGuard,
    MainComponent,
} from './../_system';

import { USERS_ROUTES, UsersComponent } from './../users';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', component:MainComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], children: [
        { path: 'users', children: USERS_ROUTES},
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/questions'}
    ]}
];

export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Comment: `router-outlet` is used with routing. Do you use routing?

Comment: Yes of course, and it refer to the main component.

Comment: so show you routes

Comment: Show some routes code.

Comment: Im just updated the post, with routes code